# Rails 4 - Missing Required Keys - Route is NOT nested

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm new to rails and following through a tutorial from pluralsight. In the tutorial, we are making a basic resume application. The problem I am having is that my resumes page fails to render on account of the following error.

```
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"resumes"} missing required keys: [:id]
```

I have looked through similar questions on stack overflow. Most other users seem to run into this issue when using nested routes. However, my route is not nested.

Here are my rails files.

Routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'job/add'
  get 'job/list'
  resources :resumes do
    member do
      get 'viewed'
    end
  end
end
```

Relevant part from index.html.erb

```
<tbody>
<% @resumes.each do |resume| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= resume.name %></td>
    <td><%= resume.phone %></td>
    <td><%= resume.email %></td>
    <td><%= resume.street %></td>
    <td><%= resume.city %></td>
    <td><%= resume.state %></td>
    <td><%= resume.zip %></td>
    <td><%= resume.summary %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', resume_path %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_resume_path(resume) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', resume, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

Relevant info from resumes_controller.rb

```
class ResumesController < ApplicationController
  # GET /resumes
  # GET /resumes.json
  def index
    @resumes = Resume.all
  end
end
```

Rake routes:

```
 Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                   Controller#Action
  job_add GET    /job/add(.:format)            job#add
 job_list GET    /job/list(.:format)           job#list
viewed_resume GET    /resumes/:id/viewed(.:format) resumes#viewed
  resumes GET    /resumes(.:format)            resumes#index
          POST   /resumes(.:format)            resumes#create
  new_resume GET    /resumes/new(.:format)        resumes#new
  edit_resume GET    /resumes/:id/edit(.:format)   resumes#edit
   resume GET    /resumes/:id(.:format)        resumes#show
          PATCH  /resumes/:id(.:format)        resumes#update
          PUT    /resumes/:id(.:format)        resumes#update
          DELETE /resumes/:id(.:format)        resumes#destroy
```

Please let me know if I have left out any information you need.

The page renders if I take out the links. However, the page is NOT populated with the information stored in resume.name, resume.phone, etc. This led me to believe that perhaps I had messed something up with the database (and maybe I have!).

I have gone into rails console and confirmed that the associated database records do exist (`Resumes.all` prints out a list of the information). So I thought that maybe the database hadn't been migrated. I ran `rake db:migrate` and tried again, but the information still does not print to the screen.

This leads me to believe that my issue is tied into the database not being accessed correctly or data not being retrieved. Server logs do show that the sql db is being queried: `Resume Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "resumes".* FROM "resumes"` .

I'm very much at a loss as to where to go from here. Any help, ideas as to where to search, anything would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In your view you have

```
<td><%= link_to 'Show', resume_path %></td>
```

I believe it is complaining that you don't provide an ID for the path.  Try changing it to

```
<td><%= link_to 'Show', resume_path(resume) %></td>
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Unfortunately, that does not fix the error. I still get the same message.